# ircd-hybrid operator configuration

Tags: irc, ircd-hybrid

I've installed ircd-hybrid server on Ubuntu, configured it, and it's up and running.

I've configured my `operator{}` section in `/etc/ircd-hybrid/ircd.conf`, setting my `name`, `user`, and `password`.  But I can't for the life of me grab /oper status on my server.  Can someone please help me with very specific instructions that are working well for them?  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know exactly what you mean about this. I struggled to figure it out myself for several hours before I figured this out:

```
operator {
    name = "root"; //Log in to oper with the name root
    user = "*@192.168.*.*";  //Allow oper from any username on the local network
    password = "YqvbpMDkkEhyY"; //hello encoded with /usr/bin/mkpasswd

    ...
};
```

With that config, you would use oper like this:

```
/oper (name) (password)
/oper root hello
```

If you get:

```
Only few of mere mortals may try to enter the twilight zone
```

Check to make sure that you are using the right name in the /oper command and the user field is including your client.

Also make sure you don't forget a semi-colon... It will not tell you, just give you the normal Password Incorrect response.

Comment: 22* *** Notice -- kirkland (~kirkland@71.22.100.124) is now an operator
22* kirkland sets mode +a kirkland
22* kirkland sets mode +l kirkland
22* kirkland sets mode +o kirkland
22* kirkland sets mode +w kirkland
22* kirkland sets mode +z kirkland
22* You have entered... the Twilight Zone!

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  So it turns out I was just using the /oper command wrong, apparently.  I was giving the username, but not the password.  Congrads on the bounty.  Thanks for your help!